# Complexity of checking $a > br^m + cr^n$, with $r$ rational

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, na.numerical-analysis

I'm wondering if the following problem is decidable in P-time (or even NP):

Given $a, b, c \in \mathbb{Z}$ and $m, n, p, q \in \mathbb{N}$ *all in binary*, decide if $a > br^m + cr^n$, where $r = {p \over q}$.

Remarks:

1. If $c = 0$, this is a very special case of the following problem, which is in P for any fixed $n$ ([Etessami et al.](https://arxiv.org/abs/1304.5429)):

Given $\vec{a}, \vec{b}, \vec{c}, \vec{d} \in \mathbb{N}^n$ *all in binary*, decide if $a_1^{b_1}\cdots a_n^{b_n} > c_1^{d_1}\cdots c_n^{d_n}$.

2. An upper bound for the above problem is given by the fact that numerical analysis is in the counting hierarchy ([Allender et al.](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/30815381_On_the_Complexity_of_Numerical_Analysis))
3. I'm particularly interested in values of $r$ very close to 1.